# Where can I get the list of standard Site labels

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, translation, force.com-sites

I am developing a multilingual site and want to use when possible the **standard** site labels. 
Where can I find the available labels to use with description and translation?

I will call them from a visualfoce page using:

```
<apex:outputText styleClass="textLogin" value="{!$Label.site.enter_password}"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a full list of site labels available here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_labelsite.htm